# Access Built-in tabs in Outlook add-in

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

My Outlook Add-in adds a recipient in a meeting invite.I need to show the "To" list when the recipient is added.How to access the built in tab in Outlook?

Comment: Do you mean you want to switch to the "Scheduling Assistant" tab?

Comment: I wish to programmatically click "invite attendees" option after I add a recipient in "To" List,just to notify the user that a recipient has been added

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to do that. You can use Accessibility API, or you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [SafeInspector](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/SafeInspector.htm) object (which wraps some of the accessibility API features)

```
set sInspector = CreateObject("Redemption.SafeInspector")
sInspector.Item = Application.ActiveInspector

'make sure "Scheduling Assistant" is shown
set Ribbon =  sInspector.Ribbon
oldActiveTab = Ribbon.ActiveTab
Ribbon.ActiveTab = "Meeting"
set Control = Ribbon.Controls("Scheduling Assistant")
Control.Execute

'MsgBox "wait" - you might need to wait for the tab to switch

'simulate a click on the "Add Attendee" button
sInspector.InvokeControl(&H00001112) ' &H00001112 is AppointmentAddAttendeeButton
```